# Proving that $⟨\phi_{n} \mid a + b \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ = ⟨ \phi_{n} \mid a \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ + ⟨ \phi_{n} \mid b \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I am trying to prove to myself that this relation is true:

> $$⟨\phi_{n} \mid a + b \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ = ⟨ \phi_{n} \mid a \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ + ⟨ \phi_{n} \mid b \mid\phi_{n} ⟩ .$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are 2 operators. So the way I was trying to solve this was by writing the state vector $\mid\phi_{n} ⟩$  as an $m\times 1$ vector, the bra $⟨ \phi_{n} \mid$ as $1 \times m$ and the 2 operator are each a matrix of $m \times m$ elements. Thus,
$$
(1 \times m) \bigg[(m \times m) + (m \times m) \bigg] (m \times 1)
$$
From the matrix multiplication rule we know that: 
$$
(m \times m) \times (m \times 1) = \mathrm{vector}(m \times 1) 
$$
and
$$
(1 \times m) \times (m \times m) = (1 \times m)
$$
Using these relations I am trying to find the result I am looking for but without success. Can someone please help.

Comment: You're essentially trying to prove that an apple is a fruit using only the fact that it is an organic object - i.e. the tools you're using are intrinsically limited and they are strictly insufficient to get you to what you want to prove (while, on the other hand, also pre-assuming the result you want on some level).

Comment: Since the Dirac notation is a relatively new way of manipulating expression to me, it happens often that I don’t necessarily understand the expression meaning in that form. In that case I try to go to the fundamental definition of the Dirac notation and visualize what is really happens when using this formalism.

Comment: Most of the time I do this I when I am not certain if a certain operation is permitted or not. So this is why I was trying to prove it this way. But it is true that when you accept the fact that $<\phi_{n}\mid(a+b) = <\phi_{n}\mid(a) + <\phi_{n}\mid(b)$

then you could write

$[<\phi_{n}\mid(a) + <\phi_{n}\mid(b) ] (\mid\phi_{n}>)= <\phi_{n}\mid(a)\mid\phi_{n}> + <\phi_{n}\mid(b)\mid\phi_{n}> $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the Dirac notation your identity reads
$$⟨φ_n,(a+b)\,φ_n⟩ = ⟨φ_n,a\,φ_n⟩ + ⟨φ_n,b\,φ_n⟩ \;.$$

It trivially holds because $a$ and $b$ are linear operators, and the inner product $⟨⋅,⋅⟩$ that defines the Hilbert space is sesquilinear.